# How adding filters model with input type date in angular

Tags: angularjs, date, input, pug

I have one problem with my filter :

```
<input type="date" ng-model="dated">
```

In

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:dated" >
  <p>{{ order.create_date | date:'dd/Mm/yyyy' }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple like this:

```
{{order.create | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I meant the ng-model does not filter because in my ng-repeat brings the day with the time and in my ng-model only this day. do not match and dont filtered.

Comment: Can you please try to explain the problem a little more?

Answer (score 0):

That would be :

```
{{order.create | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

here is a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/sRBcAol3gNhbIx4XoFCK?p=preview

The documentation says

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

That is first Parameter is the variable containng the date, then the pipe to express you'll be applying a filter then filter name 'date' and  then the other params

After your Edit.

To acheieve that you need to create a custom filter. Take a look at my plunker

Comment: thanks for the reply. I meant the ng-model does not filter because in my ng-repeat brings the day with the time and in my ng-model only this day. do not match and dont filtered.

Comment: I dont fully understand could you edit your question with more code to show what you are looking for?

Comment: why is filter and ng-model dated, what do you want to do ?

Comment: I want filter by date with the input

Comment: Edited plunker. If thats what you want please upvote :)